# Exclude WordPress cart shop when Plus Minus Button add more product not work

Tags: wordpress, varnish, varnish-vcl

When press plus bottom for add more than 1 of product to shopping cart on WordPress, Finally product add to cart after one minute, but I see this error in console:

Request URL: https://abcds.com/cart/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 503 Backend fetch failed

in my vcl I add this value but not work:

```
# The code below makes sure the AJAX "add to cart" function works
   set req.url = regsub(req.url, "add-to-cart=\d+_\d+&", "");

 # Do not cache AJAX requests.
   if (req.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest") {
       return(pass);
   }

 # Post requests will not be cached
   if (req.http.Authorization || req.method == "POST") {
       return (pass);
   }

# also in vcl_backend_response I add this codes:

  if (!(bereq.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)|login|logged-in|my-account|wc-api|resetpass|admin-ajax.php|arisn") && !(bereq.http.cookie ~ "wordpress_logged_in|woocommerce_items_in_cart|resetpass|wp_woocommerce_session_[a-zA-Z0-9]+|wordpress_logged_in_|comment_author|PHPSESSID|woocommerce_cart_hash") && !(beresp.status == 302))
     {
      unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
      set beresp.ttl = 2h;
     }
```

Related images links:

https://i.postimg.cc/hGPTFx0S/header.png

https://i.postimg.cc/BbQ7ztwk/cookies.png

update:

Varnish log:

```
<< Request  >> 20751307
Begin          req 20751306 rxreq
Timestamp      Start: 1650725983.556894 0.000000 0.000000
Timestamp      Req: 1650725983.556894 0.000000 0.000000
ReqStart       127.0.0.1 55316 a0
ReqMethod      POST
ReqURL         /cart/
ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.0
ReqHeader      X-Real-IP: 31.14.152.7
ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 31.14.152.7
ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
ReqHeader      X-Nginx: on
ReqHeader      Host: bankketab.com
ReqHeader      Connection: close
ReqHeader      Content-Length: 297
ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Opera";v="85"
ReqHeader      accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
ReqHeader      content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
ReqHeader      x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
ReqHeader      user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36 OPR/85.0.4341.75
ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
ReqHeader      origin: https://bankketab.com
ReqHeader      sec-fetch-site: same-origin
ReqHeader      sec-fetch-mode: cors
ReqHeader      sec-fetch-dest: empty
ReqHeader      referer: https://bankketab.com/cart/
ReqHeader      accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
ReqHeader      accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
ReqHeader      cookie: PHPSESSID=8beb52490b9f7ad5456f8b064a9439a5; woocommerce_recently_viewed=20077%7C20092%7C19496%7C20136; digits_countrycode=98; woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; wp_woocommerce_session_d373d61d3cf9a04133a8550c98d33197=t_df9a955c5d0c76b7f6a9ce2add86d6%7C
ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 31.14.152.7
ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 31.14.152.7, 127.0.0.1
VCL_call       RECV
ReqUnset       Host: bankketab.com
ReqHeader      host: bankketab.com
ReqURL         /cart/
VCL_return     pass
VCL_call       HASH
VCL_return     lookup
VCL_call       PASS
VCL_return     fetch
Link           bereq 20751308 pass
Storage        malloc Transient
Timestamp      ReqBody: 1650725983.557004 0.000110 0.000110
VCL_Error      Uncached req.body can only be consumed once.
Timestamp      Fetch: 1650726043.823773 60.266879 60.266769
RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
RespStatus     503
RespReason     Backend fetch failed
RespHeader     Date: Sat, 23 Apr 2022 15:00:43 GMT
RespHeader     Server: Varnish
RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
RespHeader     X-Varnish: 20751307
RespHeader     Age: 0
RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.0)
VCL_call       DELIVER
RespHeader     X-status: 0
RespUnset      X-Varnish: 20751307
RespUnset      Age: 0
RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.0)
RespHeader     X-Configured-By: ServerSetup.co
RespUnset      Server: Varnish
RespHeader     Server: Nitro
VCL_return     deliver
Timestamp      Process: 1650726043.823791 60.266897 0.000018
RespHeader     Content-Length: 285
RespHeader     Connection: close
Timestamp      Resp: 1650726043.823839 60.266946 0.000049
ReqAcct        1166 297 1463 231 285 516
End
**  << BeReq    >> 20751308

--  Begin          bereq 20751307 pass

--  Timestamp      Start: 1650725983.556958 0.000000 0.000000

--  BereqMethod    POST

--  BereqURL       /cart/

--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.0

--  BereqHeader    X-Real-IP: 31.14.152.7

--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https

--  BereqHeader    X-Nginx: on

--  BereqHeader    Content-Length: 297

--  BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Opera";v="85"

--  BereqHeader    accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01

--  BereqHeader    content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

--  BereqHeader    x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest

--  BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0

--  BereqHeader    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36 OPR/85.0.4341.75

--  BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"

--  BereqHeader    origin: https://bankketab.com

--  BereqHeader    sec-fetch-site: same-origin

--  BereqHeader    sec-fetch-mode: cors

--  BereqHeader    sec-fetch-dest: empty

--  BereqHeader    referer: https://bankketab.com/cart/

--  BereqHeader    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br

--  BereqHeader    accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9

--  BereqHeader    cookie: PHPSESSID=8beb52490b9f7ad5456f8b064a9439a5; woocommerce_recently_viewed=20077%7C20092%7C19496%7C20136; digits_countrycode=98; woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; wp_woocommerce_session_d373d61d3cf9a04133a8550c98d33197=t_df9a955c5d0c76b7f6a9ce2add86d6%7C

--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 31.14.152.7, 127.0.0.1

--  BereqHeader    host: bankketab.com

--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1

--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 20751308

--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH

--  VCL_return     fetch

--  BackendOpen    50 boot.cPanelServer 144.76.9.138 8080 144.76.9.138 34358

--  BackendStart   144.76.9.138 8080

--  Timestamp      Bereq: 1650725983.557008 0.000050 0.000050

--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1650725983.823515 0.266558 0.266507

--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1

--  BerespStatus   302

--  BerespReason   Found

--  BerespHeader   Connection: Keep-Alive

--  BerespHeader   Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT

--  BerespHeader   Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0

--  BerespHeader   X-Redirect-By: WordPress

--  BerespHeader   Location: https://bankketab.com/cart/

--  BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: woocommerce_cart_hash=3f7d291f9814ba9163415e03a89629cf; path=/; secure

--  BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

--  BerespHeader   Content-Length: 0

--  BerespHeader   Date: Sat, 23 Apr 2022 14:59:43 GMT

--  VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE

--  BerespHeader   Vary: User-Agent

--  VCL_return     retry

--  BackendReuse   50 boot.cPanelServer

--  Timestamp      Retry: 1650725983.823536 0.266578 0.000021

--  Link           bereq 19813441 retry

--  End

*** << BeReq    >> 19813441

--- Begin          bereq 20751308 retry

--- Timestamp      Start: 1650725983.823536 0.266578 0.000000

--- BereqMethod    POST

--- BereqURL       /cart/

--- BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1

--- BereqHeader    X-Real-IP: 31.14.152.7

--- BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https

--- BereqHeader    X-Nginx: on

--- BereqHeader    Content-Length: 297

--- BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Opera";v="85"

--- BereqHeader    accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01

--- BereqHeader    content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

--- BereqHeader    x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest

--- BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0

--- BereqHeader    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36 OPR/85.0.4341.75

--- BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"

--- BereqHeader    origin: https://bankketab.com

--- BereqHeader    sec-fetch-site: same-origin

--- BereqHeader    sec-fetch-mode: cors

--- BereqHeader    sec-fetch-dest: empty

--- BereqHeader    referer: https://bankketab.com/cart/

--- BereqHeader    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br

--- BereqHeader    accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9

--- BereqHeader    cookie: PHPSESSID=8beb52490b9f7ad5456f8b064a9439a5; woocommerce_recently_viewed=20077%7C20092%7C19496%7C20136; digits_countrycode=98; woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; wp_woocommerce_session_d373d61d3cf9a04133a8550c98d33197=t_df9a955c5d0c76b7f6a9ce2add86d6%7C

--- BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 31.14.152.7, 127.0.0.1

--- BereqHeader    host: bankketab.com

--- BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 20751308

--- BereqUnset     X-Varnish: 20751308

--- BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 19813441

--- VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH

--- VCL_return     fetch

--- BackendOpen    50 boot.cPanelServer 144.76.9.138 8080 144.76.9.138 34358

--- BackendStart   144.76.9.138 8080

--- FetchError     backend write error: 0 (Success)

--- Timestamp      Bereq: 1650725983.823596 0.266638 0.000060

--- FetchError     Timed out reusing backend connection

--- BackendClose   50 boot.cPanelServer

--- Timestamp      Beresp: 1650726043.823712 60.266755 60.000117

--- Timestamp      Error: 1650726043.823717 60.266759 0.000004

--- BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1

--- BerespStatus   503

--- BerespReason   Service Unavailable

--- BerespReason   Backend fetch failed

--- BerespHeader   Date: Sat, 23 Apr 2022 15:00:43 GMT

--- BerespHeader   Server: Varnish

--- VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR

--- BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

--- BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5

--- VCL_return     deliver

--- Storage        malloc Transient

--- Length         285

--- BereqAcct      2358 297 2655 394 0 394

--- End
```

Comment: Please add the output of the following logging command to your question: `sudo varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/cart' and ReqMethod eq 'POST'"`.

This will help me understand what triggers the `503` error.

Comment: This command had no output, but this command
`varnishncsa  | grep "503"` show this message:
"POST http://bbbbb.com/cart/ HTTP/1.0" 503 285 "https://bbbbb.com/cart/"

Comment: you can see Post log in this link:
https://products.groupdocs.app/editor/wysiwyg/Textual/88df3fa6-2946-4b30-a7c3-840999c1fedb/log_txt

Comment: Can you also add the full VCL file? I noticed some interesting things in the log: `VCL_Error      Uncached req.body can only be consumed once.` and the fact that a `retry` operation takes place on the backend request.

Comment: VCL file:
https://textdoc.co/jIernuGvTQ7Ez5Zx

Answer (score 1):

### The request body error

As mentioned in the comments, the following log output is quite interesting:

```
Timestamp      ReqBody: 1650725983.557004 0.000110 0.000110
VCL_Error      Uncached req.body can only be consumed once.
Timestamp      Fetch: 1650726043.823773 60.266879 60.266769
```

The `Uncached req.body can only be consumed once` error implies that your retrying a `POST` call and lose the request body in the process.

The following VCL code from your VCL file has logic that could cause this behavior:

```
if (beresp.http.Location == "https://" + bereq.http.host + bereq.url) {
    if (bereq.retries > 1)
    {
        unset beresp.http.Location;
    }
    else {
        return (retry);
    }
}
```

The fact that the request is a `POST` request where the output is a `302` redirect with a `Location: https://bankketab.com/cart/` header triggers that part of the VCL.

The problem with retrying a request that has a request body (such as a typical `POST` request), is that Varnish doesn't cache the request body. That information is lost when asking for a retry.

### The HTTP 503 backend fetch failure

All of this explains the `VCL_Error Uncached req.body can only be consumed once.` error.

The actual `HTTP 503` error could be something entirely different. However, they could be related.

The logs below refer to a `backend write error`:

```
--- BackendOpen    50 boot.cPanelServer 144.76.9.138 8080 144.76.9.138 34358
--- BackendStart   144.76.9.138 8080
--- FetchError     backend write error: 0 (Success)
--- Timestamp      Bereq: 1650725983.823596 0.266638 0.000060
--- FetchError     Timed out reusing backend connection
--- BackendClose   50 boot.cPanelServer
```

I'm not 100% sure, but it could be that the backend is waiting for the `POST` request body. It doesn't get it, times out and returns the error.

### Monitoring backend health

A backend returns an `HTTP 503` error when it is not available or when that backend doesn't return the expected result in a timely fashion.

Luckily there's a `varnishlog` command that can help us check the status of a pre-defined health probe.

Your VCL code happens to feature a `backend_healthcheck` health probe that polls the backend every 5 seconds.

Please run the following command to check the general health of your backend:

```
varnishlog -g raw -i backend_health
```

Every 5 seconds there should be a new log line with the status of the health check. Run it for a minute or so and see what the status is. If the backend is healthy, there is no critical problem with the backend. This can also help us conclude that the problem you're experiencing is really related to the absence of the request body in the retry.

### Solving the problem

My advice is to use the `std.cache_req_body()` function that is described in https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/vmod_generated.html#func-cache-req-body to ensure the request body services a `return(retry)` in the VCL code.

Here's an oversimplified VCL example that features this function:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if(std.cache_req_body(1KB)) {
        std.log("Request body accessible");
    } else {
        std.log("Request body not accessible");    
    }
}
```

A boolean value is returned from `std.cache_req_body()` describing whether or not retrieving the request body from cache was successful. You could return a synthetic error in the `else` path if you want.

> There's no guarantee that caching the request body will solve the issue, but there are indications in the log that the failure can be caused by the absence of the request body. In any case it makes sense to run `varnishlog -g raw -i backend_health` to figure out what the general health is of your backend.